# Adding all elements of same column in SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have **Price** column in my SQLite table (OrderTable). I want to add all the values in Price column, so that I can have the total price.

For example Price column has 3 values :

```
150.00  
250.00  
300.00
```

How can I get the total amount (**700.00**) using SQLite query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

total(X) where x is the column name. [Click](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) here to know more about math function in sqlite.

SELECT total(Price) AS TOTAL_PRICE FROM OrderTable; **// will result float value**

SELECT sum(Price) AS TOTAL_PRICE FROM OrderTable **// will result int value**

SAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTable (Price Integer);
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO OrderTable VALUES (NULL);  // NULL

SELECT total(Price) AS TOTAL_PRICE FROM OrderTable;  // output 6.0

SELECT sum(Price) AS TOTAL_PRICE FROM OrderTable     // output 6
```

From the [reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

> The **sum()** and **total()** aggregate functions return sum of all
>   non-NULL values in the group.
>
> ***If there are no non-NULL input rows*** 
>        then sum() returns NULL but total() returns 0.0.
>
> NULL is not normally a helpful result for the sum of no rows but the
>   SQL standard requires it and most other SQL database engines implement
>   sum() that way so SQLite does it in the same way in order to be
>   compatible. The non-standard total() function is provided as a
>   convenient way to work around this design problem in the SQL language.
>
> The result of total() is always a floating point value. The result of
>   sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any
>   input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a
>   floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.
>
> Sum() will throw an "integer overflow" exception if all inputs are
>   integers or NULL and an integer overflow occurs at any point during
>   the computation. Total() never throws an integer overflow.

Comment: I'd probably go with `sum` as that's standard and using standard SQL is a good habit. You'll get a floating point value out of `sum` if you include `insert into OrderTable values (3.14)` as well.

Comment: Yeah that's very obvious, by adding int+float will give you float value.

Comment: Only with SQLite's loose type system though, most DBs would either complain about the floating point value or silently truncate it to an integer. And you did make a point of noting that `total` and `sum` return different types.

Comment: TOTAL_PRICE is the virtual column name.